# How to set a textbox visible false but still write on it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I´m trying to set textbox visible = false to avoid user from write on it manually but I still need it to write on it by using a bar code scanner, so I need it to get focused before use the scanner, what would be the better way to do it?

Comment: If it's not visible then it can't receive focus.  Focus is entirely a construct of the interface, so something has to be *part* of the interface to receive focus.  Perhaps you can capture your scanned code into something else?  I suspect your question is based on some incorrect assumption somewhere.

Comment: Make it small or write your own control which accepts keystrokes.

Comment: It actually depends on your barcode scanner interface. Many barcode scanners work with keyboard emulation, so your application can't split keyboard input from barcode reading

Comment: A barcode scanner is usually a type of keyboard, so the users would have to be trained how to use it.  If the scanned information has a beginning character and an ending character, then you can filter the keypresses yourself by using a flag.

Comment: honestly im not sure at all as how the scanner works, the idea of make it small sounds like a good one for me, ill try it, the opacity sounds good as well but i cant find that property at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be to simply validate that what's entered into the textbox is indeed a bar code. What happens when the scanner breaks down and the user still needs to enter a bar code? Limit it to numbers only.

If that's not an option and you find the scanner doesn't work with hidden or disabled textboxes, then set `TabStop = false` and `Multiline = true`, and try setting the text box size to 0x0. Or at least really tiny and make it the same colour as the background. In that case you'd want a label or something to then display the bar code or product info so the user knows the scanning worked.

Another possibility may be to set `KeyPreview = true` on your form. Then you can handle anything that looks like a bar code in the form's `KeyPress` event, no matter which control is focused. If numbers start coming in, capture them, and if it turns out not to be a bar code, just forward them to the focused control.

Answer (score 2):

just simply set textbox property size to (0,0) with textbox visible = true

Comment: You have the solution dude, TextBox can be focused if is set VIsible = false, and TextBox can't be set color = Transparent, so size (0,0) is the only thing that worked for me :P

Answer (score 0):

From the question, you want to achieve two things.

1. Make the textbox invisible before Scanning.
2. Lock the user from editing the textbox after bar code scanning.

**Solution**

Set the textbox visibility property to `false` before Scanning so that it does appear on the screen whatsoever.

Have an event handler after finishing scanning or at the end of your scanning method/function, change the `Property` of the textbox called `Disabled` to `true`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: define "before scanning" and "finishing scanning": you method can work only if you have a reliable way to detect start and end scanning. and that's depends on how the barcode scanner works.

Comment: Yeah, am guessing you have code that calls the barcode scanner, right?

Comment: as I said, it depends on how the barcode scanner send it's data to OS and your program. If it works in keyboard emulator with no special settings, your program will receive the same input that would receive if the user press the keyboard keys corresponding to the code read. Maybe the scanner use keyboard emulation prepending a specific prefix and appending a specific suffix (e.g barcode 1234 becomes $$$1234^^^). Maybe something else. Without knowing these details, we cannot work out a solution for "detect start and end scanning"

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of hiding textbox is to not-allow user from editing it, then 
you may set the ReadOnly property of texbox to true, then call the .Focus() method
before scanning the barcode. In my experience, after having installed the barcode 
reader driver, softwares from accompanying CD, all you have to do is scan the 
barcode and it will populate with the barcode-value in human readable format, 
on any control in an application that can take user-input. I suggest to use
Readonly property of textbox instead of setting visible = false.